# Postgre: Почему не срабатывает запрос с ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, запрос, дублирование

Хочу заблокировать возможность внесения в таблицу дублей. Бросаю в Postgre следующий запрос:

```
$pg = "INSERT INTO systr.k58exp 
                    VALUES " . implode(",", $interim_arr) . " ON CONFLICT (maincolumn) DO NOTHING";
```

А она в меня швыряет: Query failed: ОШИБКА: нет уникального ограничения или ограничения-исключения, соответствующего указанию ON CONFLICT

колонку эту, maincolumn в индексы добавил.. По синтаксису запроса сверился со справочником Postgre, вроде все правильно.. В $interim_arr лежат массивы строк, которые склеиваются и отправляются в таблицу, без  . " ON CONFLICT (maincolumn) DO NOTHING" скрипт отрабатывает и благополучно укладывает строки в таблицу.. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Буду благодарен за любой совет..

Comment: *колонку эту, maincolumn в индексы добавил..* Индекс должен быть **уникальным** - иначе какой это нафиг конфликт?

Comment: Там данные формата date - но ни одного повторяющегося значения..

Comment: @Akina. Извините, начинающий, может, надо где-то специально обозначить уникальность?

Comment: Да пофиг значения! Индекс должен быть определён именно как уникальный. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ...`, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html

Comment: Я назначил эту колонку как индекс..

Comment: Правда, не запросом, а через Beaver

Comment: @Akina Я назначил эту колонку как индекс

Comment: Вы понимаете разницу между "индекс" и "уникальный индекс"?

Comment: @Akina нет, честно сказать, понял.. Изучу. Спасибо, что навели на причину..

Comment: Индекс - дополнительная структура, сортированная по выражению и используемая для ускорения обработки. Уникальный индекс - дополнительно контролирующий, что в таблице отсутствует две записи с совпадающим значением этого выражения, и блокирующем попытки создать такое дублирование, т.е. это обычный индекс + ограничение.